# Updating Layout of Panel after changing label icon

Tags: swing, layout, jpanel, jlabel

I have created a project that will download the thumbnails of the images from a ftp server and display it in a panel using JLabel. 
The images are being displayed but the layout of the panel only works if i call the panel once more (i.e using a button on the frame) then the layout corrects itself automatically. What am i doing wrong? Here is the code

EDIT- Updated the code with sscce

```
1. sscce.java 

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author Rohn
 */
public class Sscce implements Interface{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //frame.add(sci.);
        Container c=frame.getContentPane();
        JButton button=new JButton("Recall ShowCategoryImagesFunction");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sci.ShowCategoryImagesFunction("\\Nature\\Black And White"); //for testing purpose only
                                                                             // if button is pressed then we get right layout and image load
            }
        });
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        c.add(button);
        c.add(sci.ShowCategoryImagesFunction("\\Nature\\Black And White")); // default path for image load for first time
                                                                            // problem in correctly loading images and text with layout
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

2. ShowCategoryImages.java  

package sscce;  

import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient;  
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPFile;  
import java.awt.FlowLayout;  
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;  
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;  
import java.io.File;  
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;  
import javax.swing.JLabel;  
import javax.swing.JPanel;  
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;  
public class ShowCategoryImages{  
//FTPClient client=null;  
JPanel panel=new JPanel();   
JLabel label=new JLabel();  
FTPClient client=new FTPConnection().FTPConnection();  
FTPFile[] list;  
File thumbnails;  
File[] files;  
ImageIcon icon;  
public JPanel ShowCategoryImagesFunction(String path){  
// delete all the components on reload  
 if(panel.getComponents().length>0){  
     System.out.println(panel.getComponents().length);  
     panel.removeAll();  
            panel.revalidate();  
            panel.repaint();  
 }  
       //panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,4,2,2));  
 //panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));  
 panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
             panel.revalidate();  
            panel.repaint();  
            panel.updateUI();  
       try{  
           //images in /wallpapers/nature/black and white/thumb  
       client.changeDirectory("\\Wallpapers"+path+"\\thumb"); //path of thumbnails  
       //temporary folder for holding images  
       thumbnails=new File("Thumbnails");  
       list=client.list();  
       if(thumbnails.exists()){  
   files = thumbnails.listFiles();  
    if(files!=null) { //some JVMs return null for empty dirs  
        for(File f: files) {  
             f.delete();  
        }  
    }  
       }  
       else  
       thumbnails.mkdir();  
       for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){  
           System.out.println("running");  
           icon=new ImageIcon(thumbnails.getAbsolutePath()+"\\"+list[i].getName());  
           icon.getImage().flush(); 
           client.download(client.currentDirectory()+"\\"+list[i].getName(), new java.io.File(thumbnails.getAbsolutePath()+"\\"+list[i].getName()));  
label=new JLabel(list[i].getName());  
           label.setIcon(icon);  
           label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);  
           label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);  
            panel.add(label);  
            panel.revalidate();  
            panel.repaint();  
            label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){  
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){  
                JLabel la=(JLabel)e.getSource();  
                System.out.println(la.getIcon());  
            }  
            });  
           }  
            //client.disconnect(true);  
       }catch(Exception e){  
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
       }  
       return panel;  
    }  
   }




3. FTPConnection.java  

import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient;  
public class FTPConnection {  
//ftp connection on local host  
public static FTPClient FTPConnection(){  
String ftphost="127.0.0.1";  
String ftpuser="newuser";  
String ftppassword="wampp";  
int ftpport=21;   
FTPClient client=new FTPClient();  
try{  
if(client.isConnected()==true){  
client.disconnect(true);  
};  
client.connect(ftphost, ftpport);  
client.login(ftpuser, ftppassword);  
}  
catch(Exception e){  
System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
}  
return client;  
}  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not entirely sure what you mean with *not layout*, but your code is missing a revalidate/repaint after adding the labels:

```
// adding all labels
forEach (thumb....) {
   JLabel label = new JLabel(thumb);
   panel.add(label);
}
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Comment: I have not said "not layout" but distorted layout. The labels which should have been in gridLayout with text under image are appearing in random places with text either on side of image or top i.e there is no layout that is being followed
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint(); doesn't solve the problem layout is still not followed until i reload the panel again.

Comment: then it's time for an SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: I have already added the code. Since this project contains many classes it is difficult to post it here.

Comment: no, that's not  SSCCE (f.i. missing one S and therefore on C as well). It's point is to have a runnable piece of code for copying into my workspace, run and see what you are experiencing: only then is it possible to help you)

Comment: I have posted a sscce. It is just a test version some code logic may seem of no use. Just please help me with the problem of image layout and alignment.

Comment: @RohanKandwal can't do much more than repeating myself: that's still not an SSCCE (you read the article describing it, didn't you? So check that _each and every_ condition is met!)

Comment: SSCCE means a running code right? well i created a mini project from my project and created 3 java files which are executable. The only thing that might be missing in them are the thumbnails do you want them?

Comment: Read.That.Darn.Article.NOW. If you can't see why your code doesn't comply to it, I can't help you ...

Comment: then i think you can't help me more. There is nothing else that i can cut off. Problem may have arised due to FTP so i can't just remove it. It is the shortest code that i can give for the problem any more cutting may take me away from my question. Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: if you can't reproduce the problem without your ftp classes, the error is somehow related to them :-)

Comment: Ya i hoped that too that is the reason i included them. problem is i can't figure out what the problem is ;) Since on second load the images appear correctly but not on first load.